# When I create role in user with JWT, html error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'role')

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, typeerror

I am trying to add feature of role. I did what I need to do in; userModel,userController, authMiddleware.js(which is token codes).
Here is  summary of the userModel:

```
const userSchema = new Schema ({
    user_name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true,"Username area is required."],
        uniqie: true,
        validate: [validator.isAlphanumeric,"Only alphanumeric characters."]

    },
    ,
    role:{
        type:String,
        enum:["user","admin"],
        default:"user"
    },
    followers:[
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"User",
        },
    ],
    followings:[
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"User",
        },
    ],
},
```

Here is the pageRouter.js with summary (I wanna apply to the /about for test):

```
import express from "express"
import * as pageController from "../controllers/pageController.js"
import * as authMiddleware from "../middlewares/authMiddleware.js"
import User from "../models/userModel.js";

const router = express.Router()

router
.route("/")
.get(pageController.getIndexPage)
router.route("/about").get(authMiddleware.authenticateToken, authMiddleware.restrict("admin"), pageController.getAboutPage)
router.route("/register").get(pageController.getRegisterPage)

export default router
```

Here is my authMiddleware.js code:

```
const restrict = (role) =>{
  return(req,res,next)=>{
    if(req.user.role !== role){
      const error = new CustomError("No auth",403)
      next(error)
    }
    next()
  }
}
export { authenticateToken , checkUser,restrict};
```

But when I try to access my "/about", I got that error;

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'role')
```

Image of error:[image: TypeError]

edit: Also the code of pageController:

```
import User from "../models/userModel.js"




const getAboutPage = async (req,res) =>{

    const user = await User.findById({_id : req.user._id})
    res.render("about", {
        link:"about",
        user,
    })
   
}
```

edit2: Whole authMiddleware.js code:

```
import User from "../models/userModel.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";


const checkUser = async(req,res,next) =>{
  const token = req.cookies.jwt

  if(token){
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err,decodedToken)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err.message)
        res.locals.user = null
        next()
      }else{
        const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.userId)
        res.locals.user = user
        next()
      }
    })
  }else{
    res.locals.user = null
        next()
  }
}




const authenticateToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt
      
    if(token){
      jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_SECRET,(err)=>{
        if(err){
          console.log(err.message)
          res.redirect("/login")
        }else{
          next()
        }
      })
    }else{
      res.redirect("/login")
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({
        succeded: false,
        error: "Not authorized"
    })
    
  }
  
};



const restrict = (role) =>{
  return(req,res,next)=>{
    if(req.user.role !== role){
      const error = new CustomError("No auth",403)
      next(error)
    }
    next()
  }
}
export { authenticateToken , checkUser,restrict};
```

edit3: Where token create:

```
const loginUser = async (req,res) =>{
    try {
        
        const {user_name, user_password} = req.body

        const user = await User.findOne({user_name})

        let same = false

        if(user){
            same = await bcrypt.compare(user_password, user.user_password)
        } else {
            return res.status(401).json({
                succeded: false,
                error:"There is no such user",
             })
        }

        if(same) {

            const token= createToken(user._id)
            res.cookie("jwt",token,{
                httpOnly:true,
                maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
            })
            res.redirect("/users/dashboard")
        } else{
            res.status(401).json({
                succeded: false,
                error:"Passwords are not matched.",
            })
        }

        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({
                succeded: false,
                error,
             })
        }
}


const createToken = (userId) =>{
    return jwt.sign({userId},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
        expiresIn:"1d",
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code block, I see you used "," twice.

```
    user_name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true,"Username area is required."],
        uniqie: true,
        validate: [validator.isAlphanumeric,"Only alphanumeric characters."]

    },
    ,  // here
    role:{
        type:String,
        enum:["user","admin"],
        default:"user"
    },
```

And you need to check the function that generates your JWT.
You are trying to access to role by using req.user.role !== role; , but please confirm that you already used "role" for creating JWT.

Comment: Double "," is a accident when I cut some of cut while I am copying it here. 
And  I did not use "role" while i create JWT.

Comment: if you add "role"  for creating a JWT, it will be fixed.
In my opinion, req.user.role is to attempt to fetch your role from JWT, but error because you never used it for JWT

Comment: I can send you my whole JWT code, can you tell me where to exactly add it ?

Comment: please write the code to create a JWT when user sign up.

Comment: and I need to see authMiddleware.authenticateToken function, too

Comment: Yes, thet are all in authMiddleware.js. I edited the post just now. You can check.

Comment: where is encodedToken()?  I only can see decodedToken()

Comment: just generate jwt token.

let data = {  
        userId: 12, 
        role: "admin"
    } 
  
    const token = jwt.sign(data, jwtSecretKey); 

like this one.

Comment: Well, I don't have..

Comment: I am so limited about tokens... I need more general informations about it I think.

Comment: btw, if possible, please use console.log(req.user) and see what the outcome is.

Comment: I try it with functions of auth, and all feedbacks are undefined

Comment: it's problem. now you didn't create your own jwt token, and got undefined it.
it means your restrict function doesn't work at all.

Comment: Do you advice some specific website or someone for it? I need solution.

Comment: when you create your user account in backend, you have to create your own jwt token.
please check this website.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jwt-authentication-with-node-js/

if it helps you, please upvote me.

Comment: I already appreciate because of your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, I edit it again, edit3, it shows where token created. Maybe it can help you to help me.

Comment: const createToken = (userId) =>{
    return jwt.sign({userId},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
        expiresIn:"1d",
    })
}

you can modify this like the below one
const createToken = (userId, role) =>{
    return jwt.sign({userId, role},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
        expiresIn:"1d",
    })
}

Comment: I changed it as you said, still same error.

Comment: I think you might do more research about it although I explained how to access to it.
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-set-up-an-api-with-jwt-req-user-and-route-security-52f8da08cda6
I hope it will help you.